# In NextJS, how do i add getInitialProps() to a HOC-wrapped-functional-element?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, high-order-component

I have a HOC-wrapped-functional-component here

```
export default wrapperHoc( function myComponent ({ someProps }){
    return(
       <div/>
    )
})
```

How do i write `getInitialProps` for `myComponent` ?

Should i call `myComponent`'s `getInitialProps` in `wrapperHoc`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  const YourNewComponent = wrapperHoc(...)

  YourNewComponent.getInitialProps = async (ctx) => {
    const res = await fetch('https://api.github.com/repos/vercel/next.js')
    const json = await res.json()
    return { stars: json.stargazers_count }
  }

  export default YourNewComponent
```

Answer (score 0):

> Should i call myComponent's getInitialProps in wrapperHoc?

Yes, you're on the right track.

The [next.js documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/getInitialProps#caveats) says that **`getInitialProps can not be used in children components, only in the default export of every page**.

To work around this limitation, you write `getInitialProps` in myComponent, then call myComponent's `getInitialProps` in wrapperHoc. And wrapperHoc's `getInitialProps` should also be called by upper component this way.

#### wrapperHoc.js example

You're free to tweak the `getInitialProps()` to add additional properties and to tweak `render()` to add additional html elements.

```
export default (WrappedComponent) => (class WrapperHOC extends React.Component {
    static async getInitialProps(args) {
        return WrappedComponent.getInitialProps ? await WrappedComponent.getInitialProps(args) : {};
    }
    render() {
        return (
          <WrappedComponent {...this.props} />
        );
    }

});
```